# Faster K-Means Clustering in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, k-means

Dear TensorFlow Community,

I'm training a classifier with [`tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering),
but the training goes really slow, and only uses 1% of my GPU.

However, my 4 CPU cores are hitting about 35% use constantly.

Is it the case that K-Means is written more for the CPU than the GPU?

Is there a way I can shift more of the computation to the GPU, or some
other approach to speed up training?

Below is my script for training (Python3).

Thank you for your time.

```
import tensorflow as tf 



def parser(record):

  features={
    'feats': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
  }

  parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, features)
  feats = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.decode_raw(parsed['feats'], tf.float64))

  return {'feats': feats}


def my_input_fn(tfrecords_path):

    dataset = (
        tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)
        .map(parser)
        .batch(1024)
    )

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    batch_feats = iterator.get_next()

    return batch_feats


### SPEC FUNCTIONS ###

train_spec_kmeans = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn('/home/ubuntu/train.tfrecords') , max_steps=10000)
eval_spec_kmeans = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn('/home/ubuntu/eval.tfrecords') )



### INIT ESTIMATOR ###

KMeansEstimator = tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering(
    num_clusters=500,
    feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(
        key='feats',
        dtype=tf.float64,
        shape=(377,),
    )],
    use_mini_batch=True)


### TRAIN & EVAL ###

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(KMeansEstimator, train_spec_kmeans, eval_spec_kmeans)
```

Best,
Josh

Comment: Change all `tf.float64` to `tf.float32` and see if that helps.

Comment: If I go down to `tf.float32` I get a lot of `NaN`s showing up:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my best answer so far with `time` information, building off of Eliethesaiyan's answer and [link to docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance).

My original `Dataset` codeblock and performance:

```
dataset = (
 tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)
 .map(parse_fn)
 .batch(1024)
)

real    1m36.171s
user    2m57.756s
sys     0m42.304s
```

Eliethesaiyan's answer (`prefetch` + `num_parallel_calls`)

```
dataset = (
    tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)
    .map(parse_fn,num_parallel_calls=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    .batch(1024)
    .prefetch(1024)
   )

real  0m41.450s
user  1m33.120s
sys   0m18.772s
```

From the docs using `map_and_batch` + `num_parallel_batches` + `prefetch`:

```
dataset = (
    tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)
    .apply(
       tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(
          map_func=parse_fn,
          batch_size=1024,
          num_parallel_batches=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        )
    )
    .prefetch(1024)
 )

real   0m32.855s
user   1m11.412s
sys    0m10.408s
```

Answer (score 2):

one of the thing that i saw that increases gpu and cpu usage, is using prefetch on the dataset.It keeps the dataset producer fetch the data while the model is also consuming the previous batch therefore maximizing resource usage. Also specifying the  max of your cpu would speed up the process.
I would restructure it this way

```
dataset = (
    tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_path)
    .map(parser,num_parallel_calls=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    .batch(1024)
```

)

```
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1024)
```

here is a nice guide of best practice when it comes to use TfRecords [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance)

Comment: How important do you think having different variables (number of clusters, number of batches, etc) as a power of 2 helps? I have batches at `1024` but I haven't been controlling my number of clusters. Thanks!

Comment: Also from the docs you linked to: `tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch` will parallelize the batch creation, fusing `dataset.map()` and `dataset.batch()`

Comment: i am not really sure if it has an impact...but since the unit of memory is 32/64-bit, having a mutliple of the unit may be a better way to access memory...i just learn't also about tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch, seems from your measurement works faster. Thanks for the tip